# Remove javascript function when resizing screen?

Tags: javascript, resize, margin

I use this javascript in order to make 2 divs the same height, based on the content. 
However when i make the screen smaller the content of div 1 goes underneath div 2 (tried IE and FF). In other words div 1 does not stretch. However when i change the screen size and make it smaller really quick the div does stretch. When I refresh the div with a screen size below 1024px and resize it does stretch until i made the screen size above 1024 and below 1024 again.

This all is a bit fuzzy (maybe), but i made this vid to clear things out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lxe7Lr4Jt0s
Also see it live here: http://jsfiddle.net/evvwhosz/ or here: http://goo.gl/41IRWm

I found that javascript is causing this, for this reason i am trying to remove the javascript (margins) when the screen gets resized below 1024px, but its not working so far. As you can see I really put in some effort to state my problem;) This is because I am searching for a solution for so long already. Please, who can help me out?

The code is presented below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script>
  function handleMargins() {
         var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
        if(width > 1024) {
           setTimeout(function(){
        var lcol_height = $("#leftCol2").height() + 0; // add 80 for margin + padding
        var rcol_height = $("#rightCol2").height();

        if(rcol_height > lcol_height) $("#leftCol2").css('height',(rcol_height - 0) + 'px');
        else $("#rightCol2").css('height',lcol_height + 'px');
    }, 500);
        }
         else {
            return false;
        }

    }  
    jQuery(document).ready(handleMargins);
    $(window).resize(handleMargins);
    </script>
  <style>
body{ background:#f6f6f6;}
#container2 {
width: 926px;



 width:100%;
}
#leftCol2{ float:left;
    width: 300px;
    background:#FFFFFF;

    }
#rightCol2{ float:left;
width:300px;
background: #FF9;

}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
#leftCol2{float:left;
    width:100%;

    }
#rightCol2{float:left;
width:100%;
}

}
</style>  
</head>

<body>
<div id="container2">

                  <div id="leftCol2">
<p>This div is longer than the right one. This div is longer than the right one. This div is longer than the right one. This div is longer than the right one. This div is longer than the right one. This div is longer than the right one.</p>
<p>This div is longer than the right one. This div is longer than the right one. This div is longer than the right one. This div is longer than the right one. This div is longer than the right one. This div is longer than the right one.LAST</p>
    </div>
        <div id="rightCol2">
<p>Div 2.</p>


       </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not just resolving this with normal CSS? is this some kind of experiment?

Comment: @MathijsSegers They're two columns, and it seems their height is dependent on each other; CSS as a rule tends not to allow formatting dependency on previous elements. That said, solving this with JS tends to have risks too.

Comment: Hi, i need the divs to be the same height. Ive been told that when floating the divs its hard to make it work. I tried display:table, which works but then it is not supported in all browsers and ive had some problems to swap around the divs(with js, 'order' is not supported that often), see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602681/adsense-ruins-javascript-swapping-divs . Thats why i am looking for a solution with floating the divs.

Comment: Instead of floating you could also go for display:inline-block.

Comment: did you try to divide width between the too divs

       var divWidth = Math.floor($('#container2').width() / 2);
       $('#leftCol2').css({width : divWidth});
       $('#rightCol2').css({width : divWidth});

Comment: @SebriZouhaier Not sure what you mean. Define the width with javascript instead of css? Im quite new to js so pls further explain.

Comment: @MathijsSegers How to fix the equal heights of the divs then? See: http://goo.gl/oSQd2p

Comment: Just add
               var divWidth = Math.floor($('#container2').width() / 2);
               $('#leftCol2').css({width : divWidth});
               $('#rightCol2').css({width : divWidth}); before  var lcol_height = $("#leftCol2").height() + 0;

Comment: @SebriZouhaier thanks but is not reall neat. Shocks a little bit. See: http://goo.gl/Qr3Td5 and is not what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your css as below.

```
#leftCol2{ float:left;
    min-width: 300px;
    background:#FFFFFF;

    }
#rightCol2{ float:left;
min-width:300px;
background: #FF9;
}
```

Updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/evvwhosz/1/

Comment: Hi, thanks. Not fixing the problem. Causing for troubles with the max width of the container2 div. Its not floating both divs next to eachother with a screen of >1024. See: http://goo.gl/bsAKjr

Answer (score 0):

by small change in your method

```
          function handleMargins() {
                 var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
                if(width > 1024) {
                   setTimeout(function(){
               var divWidth = Math.floor($('#container2').width() / 2);
               $('#leftCol2').css({width : divWidth});
               $('#rightCol2').css({width : divWidth});     
                var lcol_height = $("#leftCol2").height() + 0; // add 80 for margin + padding
                var rcol_height = $("#rightCol2").height();
                if(rcol_height > lcol_height) 
                $("#leftCol2").css('height',(rcol_height - 0) + 'px');
                else 
                    $("#rightCol2").css('height',lcol_height + 'px');
            }, 500);
                }
                 else {
                    return false;
                }

            }
```

Comment: Hi thanks but thats not making the divs the same height see: http://goo.gl/az4Msq

Comment: because i'd like them to be 100% for mobile/small screen resolution

Comment: I want to say why you removed : 
    jQuery(document).ready(handleMargins);
    $(window).resize(handleMargins);

Comment: Where? when the screen size is below 1024 px? because, as mentioned, it gives problems with stretching the divs.

Comment: no no I see the source code of goo.gl/az4Msq and there is not call to handleMargins

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67559/discussion-between-sebri-zouhaier-and-robbertt).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the floating, is my suggestion.
use display:inline-block;
now the only thing you need to do in the media query is default them back to
display:block;
To make them sit underneath each other.

I thought this is what you needed?
If you also want to make sure they don't keep the same height. Go for an height:auto !important; in the media query.

Comment: Hi, thank you. Tried that but cant make the equal heights of the divs work. See: http://goo.gl/oSQd2p